# compiling boost.asio using g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++, boost-asio

I'm new to g++ compiler and also trying to start coding with boost.asio libraries, but have some difficulties compiling the code using g++.

I have installed boost libraries using`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` and boost folder is located in /usr/include directory, and whole scenario:

```
geek@ubuntu:~/workspace/HelloBoost/src$ g++ -I /usr/include/ -l boost_asio HelloBoost.cpp 

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_asio

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read about [using boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html) ? Apparently, it looks like a headers only library, and you only need to link `-lboost_system -lboost_regex -lopenssl`

Comment: yes, i have studied the documentation but it couldn't find the name for ASIO specifically. But thanks for the answer